ML for lot sizing task
I am solving the problem of automatic lot sizing, which consist of different products. I receive data about a certain product and I have to decide which products to combine into lots. And then producers then participate in an auction to produce the products in that lot.
I have historical data about which producers which participated in certain auctionss for certain lots in the past, the sizes of these lots, what materials they contained, in what quantities. How can i use this data to automatically form most efficient lots? Efficient lot is large with high demand (a lot of producers wanted to participate in auction)
my data looks like this:
lot_id   product_id     auction_participant       is_winner
a1        sock              John A.                 0
a1        shirt             Mike B.                 0
.....

